# “This page isn’t working” for wp-admin page

Tags: wordpress

[Got this error for wp-admin page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ykuin.jpg)

wp-admin not open any more.
I did:
1. plugin and theme folder disable.
2. checked error.log(path: root) file. But there not showing any error.
3. rename .htaccess file.

But fornt-end is okay.
I can't debugging why it is not open.

Comment: Try following steps described [here](https://www.fixrunner.com/cannot-login-wordpress-admin-area/)

Comment: @KBell I checked this line. I did all thing. not work for me.

Comment: Is there a log in your browser console/network panel when you open wp-admin ?

Comment: nothing to show on console/network:(
just show "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" on console

Comment: mmm... dont know what's happening. Consider making a fresh Wordpress install.

Comment: yes last option